# Writting Parquet file with append or overwrite, error File doesn't exist, Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I try to write my final DF with append or overwrite mode, sometimes, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/C:/Users/xxx/ScalaSparkProjects/Date=2019-11-02/part-xxxx2x.28232x.213.c000.snappy.parquet does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

And I can't understand why. This is how I am writting the DF as a parquet file:

```
df.write.mode("append")
  .partitionBy("Date")
  .format("parquet")
  .save(/data/testing/files)
```

Why could be happening this?

Comment: what happens with that folder file:/C:/Users/xxx/ScalaSparkProjects/Date=2019-11-02/ are you somehow manipulating that?

Comment: Hi @Matt I read that path before, do some transformatins and then I delete that path and try to write it again with the new DF.

Comment: thats the problem. Show me the whole code please I tell you whats wrong there

Comment: It's so big :( but the problem would be that I am reading from the same path that I am going to write it after?

Comment: I will write a quick example as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your information consider this scenario:

Source DataFrame example under the path `/tmp/sourceDF`
target path to save under `/tmp/destPath`

```
val sourceDF = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/source")
```

At this point spark reads the header of the parquet in this folder to infere the schema. The schema I used is for simplicity reasons `num: Integer`

Now what you probably think is that all data is loaded at this point, but spark works lazy until an action occurs (Actions: df.show(), df.take(1), df.count())

so this code would result in error.

```
import scala.reflect.io.Directory
import java.io.File
import spark.implicits._

val sourceDF = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/sourceDF")
val directory = new Directory(new File("/tmp/sourceDF"))
directory.deleteRecursively()
sourceDF.write.parquet("/tmp/destDF")
```

the result will be:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/source/part-00000-1915503b-4beb-4e14-87ef-ca8b99fc4b11-c000.snappy.parquet does not exist
```

In order to fix this you you have two options I can think of.

1. Change the order:

```
import scala.reflect.io.Directory
import java.io.File
import spark.implicits._

val sourceDF = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/sourceDF")
sourceDF.write.mode("append").parquet("/tmp/destDF")
// Deletion happens now after writing
val directory = new Directory(new File("/tmp/sourceDF"))
directory.deleteRecursively()
```

Or you can use a checkpoint which loads the df at some point and caches it:

```
import scala.reflect.io.Directory
import java.io.File
import spark.implicits._

// set checkpoint directory
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoint")

// cache df
val sourceDF = spark.read.parquet("/tmp/sourceDF").checkpoint()
// Now you can delete before writing it out
val directory = new Directory(new File("/tmp/sourceDF"))
directory.deleteRecursively()
sourceDF.write.mode("append").parquet("/tmp/destDF")
```

Comment: Let me check it and I will tell you Matt! Thanks in advance :D